# LDAP Filter in DN-String attribute

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to create LDAP Filter that search by part of DN-String in attribute.

If I filter with Full string, It works fine, for example:

> attrName:dn:=full_value

But if I search by part of text with *, it is Invalid:

> attrName:dn:=value*

How can I filter a DN-String attribute by part of text?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no substring match rule for distinguishedName that I am aware of.

[RFC 4517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-4.2.15) defines the distinguishedNameMatch rule as only as an equality matching rule.

Comment: Can you please give an example on how can someone use that rule? I have the exact same problem and I can't select a substring contained in DN.